# Check for a string and print the first word in the matched line in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to check if string is present in the file , if so, print the first word of the matched line(s).

sample.txt

```
id = class\234ha, class\poi23, class\opiuj, cap\7y6t5
dept = sub\6985de, ret\oiu87, class\234ha
```

in-case of string, class\234ha ,it should print : id and dept.

I know how to check if string exists using

```
File.open('sample.txt').grep(/class\\234ha/)
```

but not sure how to print the first word of matching lines. Tried using .first method but no luck.

Any help here please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything like this?

```
File.open('sample.txt').grep(/class\\234ha/) { |line| line.split.first }
 => ["id", "dept"]
```

You can pass a block to the `grep` method

Comment: Perfect, thanks. One more clarification please. what if I have read the file like below and want to check the condition above

`content =  File.open('sample.txt').read
if content.include?("class\234ha")
   Row = content.split.first
   puts "Row is: #{Row}"`

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yep, it works. But the if's condition is `content.include?("class\\234ha")`. You have to escape the backslash.